# Why this syntax for Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, syntax

What does the syntax in a for loop mean in plain English?

I'm especially confused by what is meant by

```
for X
```

In the example below, why do I use 'for letter'? Is it because 'letter' is the individual component of the thing I want to return when the function has executed?

It took me hours of switching the position of the words 'letter', 'line', 'row' and 'row_index' within the function to get something that worked.

Every function I have to write as an assignment, I have the same confusion.

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
""" (list of list of str, int) -> str

Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
as a single string.

>>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
'ANTT'
"""

line = ''

for letter in board[row_index]:
        line = line + letter

return line
```

Comment: for every letter in alphabet, print letter. `for letter in "abcdef...": print(letter)`

Comment: https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/en/loops.html

Comment: You can use `line += letter` as a short hand for `line = line + letter`. Also i think it's worth mentioning that this whole method can be done as `''.join(board[row_index])`. It will join every letter of `board[row_index]`, putting `''` (nothing) between each letter.

Comment: "It took me hours of switching the position of the..." is called cargo cult programming and it doesn't work. Please consult a tutorial and do independent research.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "why do I use `for letter`".  You can call the variable anything; you don't have to call it `letter`.

Comment: The key to understanding the Python for loop perhpas lies on the other end: there is an in and then a "container", something that contains other things. The for refers to that in the sense for each thing in the container do the following: the letter in your example is the name you give the item from the container you are currently handling. It's just a name, so in principle you could call it Peter_Paul_And_Mary but of course it's better to call it something that's suggestive of the things that actually are in  the container. The name is needed, so the loop body can reference the current item.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: "for each" ,  there are language they have for each instead of for

Comment: @Tigerhawk is there actually tutorial services for this kind of questions?

Comment: @kouty - There are many such tutoring services.

Comment: @Tigerhawk T3  I am very interested to know for me because I have a lot of questions as this and I soon that this is not adapted. This is the first time I read the concept of tutorial service

Comment: @kouty - Do a few searches on Google for tutors, tutoring services, etc., and you'll find lots of online and local outfits.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think of "for x in letter" as "for every x in letter"
For example, if you run the below code in Python:

```
small_list = ["A","B","C","D"]
for x in small_list:
    print x

You will get the output:
A
B
C
D
None
```

The above code just checked EVERY element in the list 'small_list' and printed the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the same as that which is used for existence testing;

```
letter   = 'a'
mystring = 'Hello World'
if letter in mystring:
    print("Letter "+letter+" in "+mystring)
else:
    print("Letter "+letter+" not in "+mystring)
```

In this example you are asking the interpreter a question; if `letter` (is) in `mystring` then print "the letter is in my string," otherwise print "the letter is not in my string."

A `for` loop is asking the same question except for *every* letter in the list/string/container; for (every) `letter` in `board[row_index]` concatenate the line and the letter.

The way I learned this is from my past experience with boost.foreach loops. If you've ever used them you'll understand that the loop will automatically iterate over every item in the container given a container and a buffer for the items in the container;

```
std::string hello = "Hello world!";

BOOST_FOREACH(char ch, hello)
{
    std::cout << ch; // Print each character individually
}
```

As you can see, the boost.foreach loop and Python's for loop are functionally equivalent. (As an aside you'll find that Python's for loops are far more flexible. Python's for loops will unpack lists of tuples and support branching in case the loop is not broken)

Comment: @kouty - That's C++.